# Partition list into more than 2 parts

Tags: elm

So I want to partitision a `List ItemModel` in Elm into `List (List ItemModel)`. `List.partition` only makes the list into two lists.

I wrote some code that makes the list into the parts I want (code below).

But it's not as nice of a solution as I'd like, and since it seems like an issue many people would have, I wonder are there better examples of doing this?

```
partition : List (ItemModel -> Bool) -> List ItemModel -> List (List ItemModel)
partition filters models =
    let
        filterMaybe =
            List.head filters
    in
        case filterMaybe of
            Just filter ->
                let
                    part =
                        Tuple.first (List.partition filter models)
                in
                    part :: (partition (List.drop 1 filters) models)

            Nothing ->
                []
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The returned list maps directly from the `filters` parameter, so it's actually pretty straightforward to do this using just `List.map` and `List.filter` (which is what you're really doing since you're discarding the remainder list returned from `List.partition`):

```elm
multifilter : List (a -> Bool) -> List a -> List (List a)
multifilter filters values =
    filters |> List.map(\filter -> List.filter filter values)
```

Answer (score 1):

Repeated partitioning needs to use the leftovers from each step as the input for the next step. This is different than simple repeated filtering of the same sequence by several filters.

In Haskell (which this question was initially tagged as, as well),

```hs
partitions :: [a -> Bool] -> [a] -> [[a]]

partitions preds xs = go preds xs
  where
  go [] xs = []
  go (p:ps) xs = let { (a,b) = partition p xs } in (a : go ps b)
```

which is to say,

```hs
partitions preds xs = foldr g (const []) preds xs
  where
  g p r xs = let { (a,b) = partition p xs } in (a : r b)
```

or

```hs
-- mapAccumL :: (acc -> x -> (acc, y)) -> acc -> [x] -> (acc, [y])
partitions preds xs = snd $ mapAccumL (\xs p -> partition (not . p) xs) xs preds
```

Testing:

```hs
> partitions [ (<5), (<10), const True ] [1..15]
[[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8,9],[10,11,12,13,14,15]]
```

unlike the repeated filtering,

```hs
> [ filter p xs | let xs = [1..15], p <- [ (<5), (<10), const True ]]
[[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]]
```